# Почему выходит ошибка, где параметры a: 1, b: 2

Tags: java, core

```
public class Cups {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(kuba(a: 1, b: 2));
    }
    private static int kuba(int a, int b){
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Джаве нет именованных параметров при вызове функций/методов, [в отличие от C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments), поэтому метод `kuba` следует вызывать просто: `kuba(1, 2);`

Answer (score 4):

Потому что в видео, за которым Вы это записываете, `a:` и `b:` - подсказки среды программирования, а не код.